# Create template for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I try to create a template for a custom post type, so I registered the post type:

```
function aran_create_post_types(){
    register_post_type('aran_agencies',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name'          => __( 'Agencies', 'aran' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Agencies', 'aran' ),
                'add_new_item'  => __( 'Add new agency', 'aran' ),
            ),
            'public'        => true,
            'has_archive'   => true,
            'supports'      => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'thumbnail',
                'custom-fields',
            ),
        )
    );
}
    add_action( 'init', 'aran_create_post_types' );
```

Then, I create a file called "single-aran_agencies.php", and put the following code:

```
echo "this is single agency page";
```

But when I try to view an agency post, I get 404 page. the same happen with the archive page.
Here is my single.php code, which I inherit from a parent theme:

```
get_header(); 
$show_sidebar = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'show_sidebar_checkbox', true);
if ( $show_sidebar == 'yes' ):
    $bootstrap_sidebar_dep = 'col-sm-8';
else:
    $bootstrap_sidebar_dep = 'col-sm-12';
endif;
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area <?php echo apply_filters('primary_bootstrap_class', $bootstrap_sidebar_dep); ?>">

        <div id="content-top-wa" class="widget-area">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('content-top') ?>
        </div><!-- #content-top-wa -->

        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>

            <?php faster_post_nav(); ?>

            <?php
                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->

        <div id="content-bottom-wa" class="widget-area">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('content-bottom') ?>
        </div><!-- #content-bottom-wa -->

    </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php 
    if ( $show_sidebar == 'yes' ):
        get_sidebar();      
    endif;
 ?>
    </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .container -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Any help will be appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the permalinks, [here's how to do it](https://modernthemes.net/documentation/resetting-wordpress-permalinks/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a new WP_Query for your new post type so that you'd add:

```
// Args for your Post Type:
$args = array (
    'post_type' => array( 'aran_agencies' ),
);

// The New Query
$agencies = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then you could replace:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

With

```
while ( $agencies->have_posts() ) : $agencies->the_post();
```